# replace inside a file with some specific structure

Tags: sed

I have a file look like:

```
login1.stampede(73)$ cat mc_input 
800  ! n_pass
300  ! n_equil_pass
6 6 6 ! simulation cell dimension in x, y, and z
700   ! Tinit
100   ! Tmin
700   ! Tmax
-10   ! Tinc
Li -6 Fe 0   ! mu init
Li -6  Fe 0  ! mu min
Li 6    Fe 0  ! mu max
Li 0.3  Fe 0  ! mu inc
  4  ! number of increments between structure output (0 indicates no output)
  1  ! calculate average correlations yes(1) or no (0)
  0  ! temp_chem = 0 if temperature runs 1 if chem runs
```

now I would like to target the line

```
Li -6 Fe 0   ! mu init
```

and replace -6 with another mu_init=-3, how could I achieve it with sed? thank you. Therefore the result should be :

```
Li -3 Fe 0   ! mu init
```

and "Fe 0" can be all kinds of other element-number combination and we will keep it fixed, for example "H 2", "Ge 3.2"

what i currently have is:

```
 sed -i 's,^\(Li \).*! mu init,\1$mu_init'  Fe 0   ! mu init',' mc_input
```

but it does not work....

Comment: It is not clear what your selection criteria from the original file ? From your `sed` command, it looks like you are looking for a line starting with `(Li)`, which I do not see in your source file. You need to a little more specific.

Comment: You need to clarify. Is the line you seek _always_ going to be exactly like the sample, or are you targeting all lines beginning with 'Li'?

Comment: Hi, I am targeting lines start with Li and then some number and then some other element and number and then ends with  "! mu init"... So something looks like Li #number# #another element# #another number# ! mu init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New tested version after your comment about **-3.333**:

```
sed -i "s/^\(Li \)[0-9-][.0-9-]*\(.*mu init\)/\1${mu_init}\2/" mc_input
```

### - - - -

---

For reference the first tested version:

```
sed -i "s/^\(Li \)[0-9-][0-9-]*\(.*mu init\)/\1${mu_init}\2/" mc_input
```

Some **,** in your version have been replaced with **/**.

See also other modifications: double quotes, variable, etc.

Comment: this works... may i ask if ^\(Li \) means Line start with Li but do not change during substitution and *\(.*mu init\) means ending with  mu init and [0-9-][0-9-] means the number immediately after "Li "? Thank you

Comment: ^\(LI \) means both starts with Li<space>  and it can be referenced in the replacement with \1. \(.* mu init\) means both any sequence of chars terminating with **mu init** and it can be referenced in the replacement with \2. [0-9-][0-9-] means any combination of - and digit with 2 chars after Li<space>.

Comment: I see.... Thank you so much, ehm, there is one tricky thing here, For Li -6, it might be Li - 3.333 as well.... do we have anyway to treat this situations, not limiting 2 chars digit? thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much. So [0-9-][.0-9-] means any decimal number of any length ? Thank you.

Comment: hem it means more: any sequence of chars starting with - or a digit, followed with 0 or more chars in ( digit or **.** or **-**), a mix of these.